# What resolutions should I create for photos that are uploaded

Tags: image, mobile, web, gallery, resolution

I'm currently working on my church's new website which includes a gallery. The one hiccup I ran into is that they like to upload photos that are 6mbs which is obviously not web friendly. At the time, I used a php script to thumbnail and output the image, but this time I'd like to just do that all on the upload. In other words, I want the photo to be uploaded in several different sizes - a thumbnail size, a full size for the lightbox and the original for download.

My question is what sizes should I consider. The thumbnail is obviously going to be according to the design of the site, but what about the one meant for a lightbox and should I include another resolution for let's say, mobile?

EDIT: If I'm going about this all wrong, then please lead me in the right direction!